# Dismiss View Controller without cascading all the way to root View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following UI elements (labels in Bold):

```
Root:
-----------------------
UITabBarController (A)
-----------------------
  |
----------------------------------------------
UIViewController w/ a UITableView subview (B)
----------------------------------------------
  |
--------------------------     ---------------------
UITableViewController (C)  --> UIViewController (D)
--------------------------     ---------------------
```

**A** contains **B** in its first tab. When clicking on a UITableViewCell in **B**, I am using pushViewControllerAnimated to display **C** which is much like a drilldown detail view. Finally, when clicking on a UITableViewCell in **C**, I am using presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion to show **D** in a popup modal view.

Sidenote: There is a UINavigationController on **A** and **D**.

When tapping the Close button on **D**, it dismisses the modal with:

`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

This is successfully dismissing the modal, but it also is backing out of **C** all the way back to **B**. I would like to stay at **C** instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have navigation controllers on A and D? From the description you gave, it sounds like you should have B embedded in one, an no others.

Comment: A has a navigation controller because I want a tab bar and a nav bar. I added it on D because when I present the View Controller the nav bar is lost again.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you should call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Have a try. My guess is based on Apple's doc:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the
>   presenting view controller.

So if you call  dismiss on `self.presentingViewController`. Then **B** will dismiss!